# Make \section*{} compatible with the exam class

Tags: sectioning, exam

I'd like to redefine the `\section*{}` command so that the section title are aligned left. I actually can achieve it with `\fullwidth{\section*{my section title}}`
but y would like to do something like:

```
\renewcommand\section*{\fullwidth{\section*{#1}}}
```

which of course does not work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I just tested it, and for me the section titles *are* aligned left. Has the exam class changed recently?

Answer (score 4):

Since the `exam` class is built on `article`, a standard method for this would be

```
\makeatletter
\let\article@section\section
\renewcommand\section{\@ifstar\fullwidth@section\article@section}
\newcommand{\fullwidth@section}[1]{\fullwidth{\article@section*{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a problem with @egreg solution: redefining sections like that, the possibility of referencing sections is lost.

With referencing sections I mean using a `label` after any section, and anywhere in the code using `ref`. Doing this, you only get `??` no matter how many compilations you do with the code.

The solution I came up with is using `titlesec` package:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\fullwidth}
```

The drawback of this method is that you must put `\fullwidth` as the last element of `titleformat`.

The same can be achieved with subtitles (doing the proper changes of course).

Comment: Out of the half a dozen or so solutions I've found, yours is the one that's the shortest and works the best. Thanks!